# How to print dynamic text on image at any given coordinates in angular 6

Tags: css, angular

I am selecting an image file and showing on a modal. What I want to do is, I want to write some text on this selected image.

User will enter whatever text he/she wants to print on image in a text box (id="TextData") and wherever user clicks on image that text will be printed at the position, where user has clicked.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
          </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1 caption">
             <input type="text" id="TextData">
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7">
       <div class="my-custom-scrollbar d-inline-block">
           <img [src]="url">
       </div>
   </div>
```

code is as above. I have also written code to get the coordinates where user has clicked (x and y positions).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function(e) {
      const offset = $(this).offset();
      const X = (e.pageX - offset.left);
      const Y = (e.pageY - offset.top);
      console.log(X);
      console.log(Y);
    });
  });
```

Now I want to print user's text at that position. User can also change color of text to be written on image. How to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So create element with `position: absolute; left: {{X}}, top: {{Y}}`

Comment: @Justinas Thank you. It is printing text. But it is taking x and y coordinates of document. Actually my application has Modal , on that modal there is a tab and in that tab, I am showing image. So i want to print on image. Currently it is not printing on image. It is printing on x and y coordinates of document and not image.

Comment: So again simple css. Make sure your image wrapper (that will contain also text) have `position: relative`. And make sure your `X` and `Y` is correct

Comment: @Justinas One more problem is as i told you that I have to show image to user and user should be able to write/print text at any location/position on image. its printing text but if i close my modal then that text is still there on main screen/component. Means, that text is not printed on image. Actually, I also want to save that image with text but currently i am not able to save because that text is not on image. I hope you understood what i said. sorry for my english